# How to traverse the input field in the Google search result page and auto focus on it?

Tags: javascript, events, focus

I want to set a shortcut to focus on the input field in the Google search result page, instead of using mouseover or mousemove Event.

How to traverse all the elements in a page to get the input field to execute `focus()` by using Javascript.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
        var keynum;
        if(window.event) // IE
        {
            keynum = event.keyCode;
        }
        else if(event.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        {
            keynum = event.which;
        }
        console.log(event.keyCode)

        if(keynum==79&&event.altKey){
          //get the input element in a page and execute focus()
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to get the search bar element, we need to use the `querySelector`. After that, we need to focus on the input. Even after this, we will not see the automatic suggestions that google gives us. So, we also need to stimulate the `click` event. The below code will do the work -

```
let searchBar = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");
searchBar.focus();
searchbar.click();
```

Comment: And it is a headache that there is no type of input in some of the sites, and there are many input elements, so this is only suited for the site in which input type is text, as Google search results.

Comment: @lyscop yes it is indeed. However, you cannot predict which site will use which type of input and what will be their order. I just inspected the google search results page and found the particular input. If you have to use this somewhere else, then you will have to tweak into the site's html to find the way to search bar.